# How to get the value of an input field in Phoenix Framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to get the input text from an html input, which is supposed to be a message in a chat. Then I want to add that text to the chat history below.

My (updated!) code so far:

```
defmodule ChatWeb.ChatLive do 
    use ChatWeb, :live_view
    
        def mount(params, session, socket) do
            {:ok, assign(socket, :text_value, "")}
        end
        
        def render(assigns) do
        ~H"""
            <h1>Chat</h1>
            <form phx-submit="submit">
            <label>Your Text:<input id="msg" type="text" name="input_value" /></label>
            <button>Send</button>
            </form>
            <div id="chat">
                Chat history: <%= @text_value %>
            </div>
            
        """
        end
        
        def handle_event("send-msg", %{"input_value" => msg}, socket) do
            {:noreply, assign(socket, :text_value, msg)}
        end
        
end
```

This is what it looks like so far:

[image]

Comment: What’s issue do you have? What’s not working?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I need to get the value that is put into the html input and concat it to the text_value variable. I am missing some general understanding of how to do that. In the updated code snippet above the issue is that the text is not added to the text_value.

Comment: `assign(socket, :text_value, msg <> socket.assigns.text_value)` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this `handle_event` function:

```
    def handle_event("send-msg", %{"input_value" => msg}, socket) do
        {:noreply, assign(socket, :text_value, msg)}
    end
```

... but it doesn't look like `"send-msg"` is being bound to anything. Here's more info about bindings in LiveView, including a code example: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-bindings

It looks like your "Send" button is currently bound to the `"submit"` event, via this code:

```
<form phx-submit="submit">
```

If you just change the `"send-msg"` `def handle_event("send-msg"...` to `"submit"`, it works fine and `text_value` gets assigned to the value of the input box as expected.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of your answers and comments (Thanks!) I was able to solve it like this:

> defmodule ChatWeb.ChatLive do
> use ChatWeb, :live_view
>
> ```
>     def mount(params, session, socket) do
>         {:ok, assign(socket, :text_value, "")}
>     end
>     
>     def render(assigns) do
>     ~H"""
>         <h1>Chat</h1>
>         <form phx-submit="submit">
>             <label>Your Name:<input id="client" type="text" name="client" /></label>
>             <label>Your Text:<input id="msg" type="text" name="input_value" /></label>
>             <input type="submit" />
>         </form>
>         <div id="chat">
>             Chat history: <%= @text_value %>
>         </div>
>         
>     """
>     end
>     
>     def handle_event("submit", %{"input_value" => msg, "client" => client}, socket) do
>         {:noreply, assign(socket, :text_value, "| Message by " <> client <> ": '" <> msg <> "' " <> socket.assigns.text_value)}
>     end
>     
>      end
> ```

Comment: if my answer helped you, mind upvoting/marking it as accepted?